# Link Json data on key ID to create brand new Json file

Tags: python, json, powershell, flutter, dart

I have a Json file which has stations and prices array, I would like to have this linked so all required data are in one array.

```
{
  "stations": [
    {
      "code": "1",
      "name": "United force"
    },
    {
      "code": "2",
      "name": "Toowoon Bay Service Station"
    }
],

 "prices": [
    {
      "stationcode": "1",
      "fueltype": "DL",
      "price": 126.97
    },
    {
      "stationcode": "1",
      "fueltype": "E10",
      "price": 118.92
    },
    {
      "stationcode": "2",
      "fueltype": "E10",
      "price": 112.90
    },
    {
      "stationcode": "2",
      "fueltype": "P95",
      "price": 125.90
    },
    {
      "stationcode": "2",
      "fueltype": "P98",
      "price": 155.90
    },
    {
      "stationcode": "2",
      "fueltype": "U91",
      "price": 115.20
    }
 ]
}
```

Expected outcome of new Json create Json will be

```
{
  "stations": [
    {
      "code": "1",
      "name": "United force",
      "DL": 126.97,
      "E10": 118.92
    },
    {
      "code": "2",
      "name": "Toowoon Bay Service Station",
      "E10": 112.90,
      "P95": 125.90,
      "P98": 155.90,
      "U91": 115.20
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to do this transformation that will not be on the client side, like may be powershell or python or dart that I can just run so I have the new generated file (or schedule), the generated file will be used as the source in my app (Flutter). Because transformation would be expensive/time consuming if doing it on the fly on the client side.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this would convert the json in powershell fashion:

```
$data = @"
{
  "stations": [
    {
      "code": "1",
      "name": "United force"
    },
    {
      "code": "2",
      "name": "Toowoon Bay Service Station"
    }
],

 "prices": [
    {
      "stationcode": "1",
      "fueltype": "DL",
      "price": 126.97
    },
    {
      "stationcode": "1",
      "fueltype": "E10",
      "price": 118.92
    },
    {
      "stationcode": "2",
      "fueltype": "E10",
      "price": 112.90
    },
    {
      "stationcode": "2",
      "fueltype": "P95",
      "price": 125.90
    },
    {
      "stationcode": "2",
      "fueltype": "P98",
      "price": 155.90
    },
    {
      "stationcode": "2",
      "fueltype": "U91",
      "price": 115.20
    }
 ]
}
"@ | ConvertFrom-Json

foreach ($price in $data.prices) {
    $data.stations | 
    Where-Object { $_.code -eq $price.stationcode } |
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $price.fueltype -Value $price.price
}

$data | Select-Object -Property stations | ConvertTo-Json
```